# Which expression is correct “in purpose” or “on purpose”?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage, phrases

I'm frequently encountering English proofreading problems. For now I am trying to figure out which one of these two is the correct form: **in purpose** or **on purpose**. I tried to Google and found both forms used in various web-pages. If both of these forms are correct, please explain when which one is better to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[***on purpose***](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+purpose) is what's used. This is a legitimate expression in English with its own entry in the dictionary. It means intentionally. I myself use it all the time. As for the other one, I have never ever heard anyone say ***in purpose*** in place of ***on purpose***. That would just sound wrong.

However, you could say ***in purpose*** in certain situations, but that would mean a totally different thing. For example:

> This thing is completely useless ***in purpose*** as well as in use.

Meaning, it for whatever reason does not have a purpose and thus is considered useless.

Comment: Thank you very much. I vote up your answer. I need just some points to make my up-votes visible.
I believe the answers of native English speakers, but here I found this phrasal verb in this online dictionary: https://www.thefreedictionary.com/In+purpose I guess this dictionary contains wrong data as well

Comment: Read carefully what that dictionary says: **On purpose** is the form now generally used.

Comment: note: the opposite phrase is technically "by accident", not "on accident", though "on accident" is often used informally

Answer (score 0):

on purpose is correct. the other way to say this could be “for the purpose of (x), they did (y). “

examples: “He was upset with his brother, so he burnt his toast on purpose.”
or
“for the purpose of grading the tests faster, the teacher decided to have the students work in groups during class.”